# Use VBA to click on a button in IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, buttonclick

I'm currently looking for a way to click on a button on a web page to automate an export.

I've already succeeded with logging in to the web page and clicking on the login button to redirect the page, but then I could not click on the next button i'm looking for.

My code :

```
For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("ul")
 If ele.document.getElementsByTagName("a").getAttribute("aria-labelledby") = "Exporter vers CSV" Then ele.Click
Next
```

Website source:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
   <!-- ngRepeat: item in secondaryItems track by item.dataAid --><li ng-repeat="item in secondaryItems track by item.dataAid" class="">
     <a role="button" ng-show="item.visible" aria-labelledby="Exporter vers CSV" data-aid="tool-bar-inner-dd-btn-export" type="submit" ng-disabled="!item.enabled" ng-class="{plToolbarItemDisabled:!item.enabled, disabled:!item.enabled}" class="grid-export-item-btn" ng-click="item.callback(item, $event)" pl-toolbar-button-in-dropdown="" item="item">
```

Comment: I once faced a similar problem. In the end I just ended up checking whether or not I was logged into the site by the return url. If not logged in I prompted an error message telling the user to log in and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test it without knowing your URL, but this maywork:

```
For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("ul")
    For Each ele2 In ele.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If InStr(ele2.InnerHtml, "aria-labelledby=""Exporter vers CSV""") Then ele2.Click
    Next ele2
Next ele
```

Comment: Hi, i couldn't gave you the URL cause it's an internal one, from my company, thank you it Works !

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go. When you are upon `instr()` function then simply the below method should get you there.

```
For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(ele.getAttribute("aria-labelledby"), "Exporter vers CSV") > 0 Then ele.Click: Exit For
Next ele
```